# On Scribblenauts Remix level 4-3, how do I get the Doctor to enter the cell?

Tags: scribblenauts-remix

What object do I have to give the prisoner to get the doctor to go into the cell?

This isn't the psychologist - I got that one already - without the help of StackExchange :)

Comment: I was stuck on this level for ages because of the nurse one. Everything was so easy apart from this....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a snake in the prison cell

Answer (score 3):

Try hurting the prisoner in some way, the doctor should run in to help. The solution I used is under the spoiler block so you can ponder your own methods for achieving hurt.

> In the style of classic cartoons, spawn a Heavy Safe above him and let it drop on his head.

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck in this level five minutes ago. Try "president".

Answer (score 2):

"bad food" works for opening the doctor's door. Fire did NOT help.

Answer (score 2):

put a "sick potion" in the prisoner's hand.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to give the doctor a flamethrower, and then you drop a disease on the prisoner's head.

Answer (score 0):

Each of them need a certain thing to get them to go in. The doctor helps . Make the prisoner beside her hurt/ sick. Put a mud puddle in the cell beside the janitor. Type  fire. And put that inthe cell next to the fireman. I haven't figured out what to do for the teacher yet but I'll update when I do

Answer (score 0):

you can put a vampiric ant in the cell

Answer (score 0):

"Infectious ant" also works to get the doctor into the cell.